# Enable multiple threads to share the same socket using lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, semaphore

I have a socket that I use to communicate with a controller from multiple threads doing different tasks. Currently, I carefully constructed access to the socket to make sure a lock isn't taken multiple times within the same thread so I don't end up with a dead lock. I would like to remove this restriction if possible. I found with .net 4.5 and newer I can use the Monitor class's IsEntered method, but how can I do this on earlier frameworks? Primarily, .net 3.5CF which does not have the IsEntered method. I need the lock to keep a single thread from hogging access to the socket. I achieved this in the class below by putting an outer lock around access to the inner lock which protects access to the socket.

```
public class SyncLock
{
    private object inner, outer;

    public SyncLock()
    {
        inner = new object();
        outer = new object();
    }

    public void Enter()
    {
        if (Monitor.IsEntered(inner))
        {
            Monitor.Enter(inner);
        }
        else
        {
            lock (outer)
            {
                Monitor.Enter(inner);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        Monitor.Exit(inner);
    }
}
```

To use this class, I create a shared instance of the SyncLock class with the following around locked code.

```
SyncLock syncLock = new SyncLock();

...

syncLock.Enter();
try
{
...
}
finally
{
    syncLock.Exit();
}
```

Comment: _"I carefully constructed access to the socket to make sure a lock isn't taken multiple times within the same thread so I don't end up with a thread lock"_ -- do you mean "dead lock"? "Thread lock" doesn't mean anything useful. In your code, what is the point of having two monitors? Note that locks are safely re-entrant; a thread that already has the lock can acquire it again without blocking. Please fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] showing what behavior you're trying to avoid, and explain what _specifically_ you're unable to figure out.

Comment: Yes, I meant dead lock. I have two monitors so a single thread cannot hog access to the socket. (Second thread holds outer monitor keeping first thread from re-acquiring inner monitor until it gets a turn.) The problem is I need this code to run on a device which only supports .net 3.5 compact framework and 3.5 does not support the Monitor.IsEntered function. Is there another method to determine "IsEntered" on .net 3.5? Currently, the only solution I know is to just not including the "IsEntered" check which requires care to not create a dead lock.

Comment: _"I have two monitors so a single thread cannot hog access to the socket"_ -- how would a single thread hog access? And how does having two monitors solve that problem in your scenario? Fundamentally, it seems that there's a good chance that you simply don't understand how the locks work in the first place, and have written code that is unnecessary and/or doesn't do what you think it does. There are certainly ways you could implement to keep track of whether a thread has acquired a lock, but you shouldn't need to. Post a better question, with a [mcve] showing the behavior you want to avoid.

Comment: Within the lock, the thread sends request data over the socket then waits for a response. Outside the lock it processes the response data then goes to re-enter the lock with a new request. The time it takes to receive a response is generally longer than processing the data so with only a single lock the thread gets back in and waits for the next response before another thread is able to get in and make a request. I'm using the second lock to keep the first thread from getting back in the lock without first giving the other thread access.

Comment: I am dubious of a design where multiple threads write to the same socket. But, it sounds like the main problem you have is that you're using synchronous I/O when in fact you should be using async I/O. The only lock you should need is for writing to the socket. Async methods to retrieve data from the socket can be used, and there's no need to lock the socket for the duration of the waiting for the response. You also have problems in your locking design, but by stepping back and solving the problem more elegantly, those issues just go away.